# How to declare supertraits Into<T> so it works with both move and borrow?

Tags: rust

I want to declare a `trait T` that has two super traits `Into<R>` so the into accepts both `T` and `&T`

```
fn into(self) -> R;
fn into(&self) -> R
```

How to fix compile error?

```
use strum::IntoStaticStr;

trait EnumIntoStaticStr: Into<&'static str> {}
impl<T: Into<&'static str>> EnumIntoStaticStr for T {}

#[derive(IntoStaticStr)]
enum MyEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar(String),
}

fn main() {
    let v = MyEnum::Foo;
    let str = borrow_into_str(&v);
    drop(v);
    println!("{}", str);
}

fn move_into_str(v: impl EnumIntoStaticStr) -> &'static str {
    v.into()
}

fn borrow_into_str(v: &impl EnumIntoStaticStr) -> &'static str {
    v.into()
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: From<&impl EnumIntoStaticStr>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:7
   |
24 |     v.into()
   |       ^^^^ the trait `From<&impl EnumIntoStaticStr>` is not implemented for `&str`
   |
   = note: required for `&impl EnumIntoStaticStr` to implement `Into<&str>`
help: consider dereferencing here
   |
24 |     (*v).into()
   |     ++ +

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can since the impl for `&T` would conflict with the impl for `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, this is the declaration you're looking for:

```rust
trait EnumIntoStaticStr
where
    Self: Into<&'static str>,
    for<'a> &'a Self: Into<&'static str>,
{}
impl<T> EnumIntoStaticStr for T
where
    T: Into<&'static str>,
    for<'a> &'a T: Into<&'static str>,
{}
```

However, the compiler doesn't accept this in actual usage; in general, it [currently can't make use of](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20671) implied bounds that aren't of the form `Self: Foo` (that is, the left side is exactly `Self`, not `&Self` or anything else), whether or not they are written using the supertrait syntax `trait Bar: Foo`.

A solution is to write methods that directly express what you want instead of making `Into` do the work:

```rust
trait EnumIntoStaticStr {
    fn into_str(self) -> &'static str;

    fn to_str(&self) -> &'static str;
}

impl<T> EnumIntoStaticStr for T
where
    T: Into<&'static str>,
    for<'a> &'a T: Into<&'static str>,
{
    fn into_str(self) -> &'static str {
        self.into()
    }

    fn to_str(&self) -> &'static str {
        self.into()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = MyEnum::Foo;
    let str = v.to_str();
    drop(v);
    println!("{}", str);
}
```

(Note that these methods follow Rust naming conventions for conversion methods: `into_*` takes ownership and `to_*` borrows.)